# Why am I getting unknown column in field list, I am trying to extract data from few columns

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

Select Clause and Error

```
mysql> SELECT deviceDetails.lastUpdatedDate,connectionDetails.phoneNumber1,
deviceDetails.simImea1,deviceDetails.simImea2,deviceDetails.model,
connectionDetails.latitude,  connectionDetails.longitude  from connectionDetails c 
inner join deviceDetails d  on (c.deviceUniqueIdentity = d.deviceUniqueIdentity && d.rowStatus='0')  
INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/merged.csv'  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','  ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

Error

```
   ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'deviceDetails.lastUpdatedDate' in 'field list'
```

Table schema

```
mysql> describe deviceDetails;
+------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field                  | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| activationDate         | bigint(20)   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| lastUpdatedDate        | bigint(20)   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
```

Comment: Why the -ve vote ? Care to explain Mr Downvoter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have created the alias for the tables and hence they need to be used in the select as well

```
SELECT 
d.lastUpdatedDate,
c.phoneNumber1,
d.simImea1, 
d.simImea2,
d.model,
c.latitude, 
c.longitude  
from connectionDetails c inner join deviceDetails d  on (c.deviceUniqueIdentity = d.deviceUniqueIdentity && d.rowStatus='0')
```